# ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype error when query from oracle to mysql over dblink

Tags: mysql, oracle, dblink

I created a db link from Oracle (19c) to MySQL (8.0). My MySQL table's columns datatypes are text (I mustn't change the datatype). There are 126 columns in the table (It must be such). When I try to query to MySQL in oracle sqlplus it gives "ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype" error. I tried to many thing including creating a view in MySQL with casted fields to char or varchar but not solve the problem. When I do "desc view_table@dblink" in oracle sqlplus columns are still appeared as long datatype. Is there a way to solve it? What can I do? I stucked here.

Comment: I would have expected Oracle to have dropped the LONG datatype by now, seems not.  Many inconveniences, amongst others that they can't be used over a database link.  You could switch to using CLOB.

Comment: What driver are you using for DB Link from Oracle to MySQL?

Comment: @MichaelKutz I used dg4odbc

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yes you right. Also, it is very frustrating that is incompatibility between two Oracle products.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to use CLOB in MySQL.

Comment: @HarunCetin: Yes, they are /now/ both owned by Oracle Corporation, but they acquired MySQL out of the "garage clearance sale" that was Sun Microsystems.  Totally different lineages.

Comment: Would it be feasible to create a copy of that table in Oracle, and have an external program keeping it in sync with the one in MySQL?

Comment: @PhillW. - same for Rdb.  Early in my DBA career I attended an Rdb course, shortly after Oracle had acquired Rdb from DEC. The instructor was an old Rdb hand and said that Oracle had intended to merge the two, but after the "suits" had done the deal and the engineers started looking at the details, they said there was "no way".  I'm sure the same applied to the acquisition of MySQL.

Comment: `CLOB` corresponds to `TEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT`, or `LONGTEXT`, depending on max size.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you, I know it. I stated above that my Oracle database is on Oracle Linux server and I use unixODBC to establish a dblink to MySQL from Oracle. My MySQL tables' fields are TEXT (mandatory) and dg4odbc doesn't recognize TEXT datatype and see those as a LONG typed fields. I need to overcome that issue.